# Passing in a different parameter type than the one specified works in Golang?

Tags: go, struct, dependencies, code-injection

I have 3 packages total: repository, restrict, and main.

In my repository package, I have a structure called "RestrictionRuleRepository" defined as:

```
type RestrictionRuleRepository struct {
    storage map[string]float64
}
```

In another package restrict, I have a "NewService" function defined:

```
func NewService(repository rule.Repository) Service {
    return &service{
        repository: repository,
    }
}
```

Finally, in my package main, I have these two lines of code:

```
ruleRepo := repository.RestrictionRuleRepository{}

restrictionService := restrict.NewService(&ruleRepo)
```

My code is compiling without any errors. Why is this allowed in Golang? Doesn't my NewService function expect a Repository type, but I am passing in the address of a RestrictionRuleRepository struct to it?

Comment: What is `rule.Repository`? You haven't defined it anywhere, so it's impossible to answer your question. (it's probably an interface from the looks of it, but it's better that you define it than have people guessing to try to answer your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely `rule.Repository` is an interface and the `*RestrictionRuleRepository` type just happens to implement that interface.

Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Repository interface {
    SayHi()
}

type RestrictionRuleRepository struct {
    storage map[string]float64
}

func (r *RestrictionRuleRepository) SayHi() {
    fmt.Println("Hi!")
}

type service struct {
    repository Repository
}

type Service interface {
    MakeRepoSayHi()
}

func NewService(repository Repository) Service {
    return &service{
        repository: repository,
    }
}

func (s *service) MakeRepoSayHi() {
    s.repository.SayHi()
}

func main() {
    ruleRepo := RestrictionRuleRepository{}
    restrictionService := NewService(&ruleRepo)
    restrictionService.MakeRepoSayHi()
}
```

This compiles fine as you can see in https://play.golang.org/p/bjKYZLiVKCh.

I also recommend https://tour.golang.org/methods/9 as a good place to get started with interfaces.